# Error:Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-livedata

When I press the run button in Android Studio, my app compiles but shows this error (redacted):

```
Error:Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
```

[(Full log)](https://pastebin.com/wS4nxXBu)

I've tried deleting the `.gradle` folder, then going to `Build > Clean Project` and `Build > Rebuild Project`. However, it doesn't work. I've also tried deleting the source code, then cloning again from `git` and importing the folder to Android Studio. However, it still produces that error.

Here's my app's `app/build.gradle`:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.edricchan.studybuddy"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0.0-rc.503"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resConfigs "en"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Firebase stuff
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.1.0'
    // Provide a way to update the app
    implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:AppUpdater:2.6.4'
    // Chrome Custom Tabs
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0'
    // The app's intro screen
    implementation 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:1.6.2'
    // Use for new Material Text field boxes recently introduced
    implementation 'com.github.HITGIF:TextFieldBoxes:1.3.7'
    // Report an issue to Github without having to open a new tab and so on...
    implementation 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:android-issue-reporter:1.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I've just reported this issue to Google's Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74130804

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Apparently, this is intended behavior:

> com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.1.0 depends on android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1. Switching to version 3.2.2 fixes the issue by using the Lifecycle 1.1 libraries that Support Library 27.1.0 are built upon. - [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74130804)

For me, removing the `firebase-ui` dependencies solved the issue since I wasn't even using the library in the first place.

Comment: And with that, the long road to upgrading Android Studio is over... thanks!

Comment: I dont even use firebase-ui  but still getting this error

Comment: @EgeKuzubasioglu Can you post a new question?

Comment: @Edric turned out an external libraries merge dex issue were causing this, I removed that library from my project

Comment: In my case removing dependencies related to fuel worked (com.github.kittinunf.fuel)

Answer (score 26):

I had the very same problem today when I raised the support library version.

Try to replace **all** '27.1.0' with '27.0.2'

---

Later on I did manage to remove the error by upgrading other libraries as well.
THis is my current working state:
root gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
    ext.support_version = '27.1.0'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.4'
    ext.android_plugin_version = '3.0.1'
    ext.google_services_version = '11.8.0'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-beta4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

//////////////////
app gradle libraries:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // kotlin:
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.22.3'

    // support libraries:
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$support_version"

    // misc:
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5'
    implementation 'com.backendless:backendless:4.4.0'
    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'

    // Google services:
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$google_services_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$google_services_version"
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$google_services_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$google_services_version"

    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
    }
}
```

///////////////

I also upgraded graddle-wrapper.properties to:

```
#Wed Dec 20 15:08:34 CET 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Comment: Later, I did manage to remove the error by upgrading other libraries.

Comment: Thanks! Downgrading solved the problem. How did you solve it after downgrading?

Comment: Which libraries did you upgrade? I can't tell

Comment: I've just reported this issue to Google's Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74130804

Answer (score 21):

This post is the top search result for the very similar error: "Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.**ViewModelProvider$Factory**"

My project uses Room and LiveData, but not firebase. The following changes removed the error:

FROM:

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0'
```

TO:

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'
```

--- UPDATED ANSWER ---

My previous answer was aimed at solving this error. However, I thought it would be worth presenting it again using best practises:

App level build.gradle file:

```
// Room components
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

// Lifecycle components
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
```

Project level build.gradle file:

```
ext {
   roomVersion = '1.1.1'
   archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'
}
```

Reference:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#2

Comment: thx! the only answer which actually worked. Im not using room though, but upgrading lifecycle dependencies helped and now my project builds!

Answer (score 3):

Firebase-UI 3.1.0 isn't compatible with Firebase / Google Services 11.8.0

You will need to upgrade or downgrade according to https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries

- Firebase-UI 3.1.0 with Firebase / Google Services 11.4.2
- Firebase / Google Services 11.8.0 with Firebase-UI 3.1.3

Hope this help ;)

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can either upgrade `firebase-ui` to `3.2.2` or completely remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the error posted in the original question, namely:

```
Error:Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
```

It wasn't clear which libraries were causing the problem. With a hint from @lienmt above I realized that it may be related Firebase.

In my case, I am using Firebase and was also using firebase-ui library 3.2.2:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
```

I had upgraded all my other Firebase libraries to 15.0.0 but realized my firebase-ui library was incompatible and confirmed it here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries

Be sure to match your firebase-ui version to the exact Firebase versions that for which they are fixed for pairing.

Bumping my firebase-ui version to 3.3.1 was what resolved the error:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
```

For reference here are the versions I'm using now and my app is running with no errors:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can either upgrade `firebase-ui` to `3.2.2` or completely remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Please add following dependencies in your app build.gradel file

```
implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.core:common:1.1.1"
```

Comment: Describe how this solves his issue.  So it'll be more easier to understand.

Comment: @rishad2m8 I've already solved my issue, although others may find other solutions here useful.

Answer (score 0):

@Edric: since I couldn't replay with images in the thread I am answering your question here.

Changes that worked for me:

[image: Module]
[image: Project level]

PS: I also upgraded distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties to
http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

Comment: I already saw the change you made to `gradle-wrapper.properties`, it's just the `build.gradle`. Oh, and by the way, the issue that I have reported has been assigned to a Googler.

Comment: Anyway.. now you have ALL the exact changes made that worked for me ...in one place

Answer (score 0):

Like Edric mention, this happens because some library still use the old version of android.arch.lifecycle:extensions library, that is `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0`.

One way to handle this is by forcing the app to use the same version of that library (and if we can, use the newest one).

There are two ways to do that:

1. Explicitly defined the library version that we want to use in our Gradle, under dependencies section.

   `implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1`

or

2. Force resolution of the library, also under `dependencies` section.

   ```
   android {
       configurations.all {
           resolutionStrategy.force 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, bumping `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to 28, as well as using version 28 of all support libraries fixed the issue.

---

I encountered this when I upgraded Glide. I got an error regarding a [duplicate CoordinatorLayout](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3032). I [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49112190/3979290) that by using `com.android.support:design:27.1.0`, but then I got another error regarding `LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver`.

After a few hours, I gave up and upgraded `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to API 28, as well as using

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

because YOLO. By dumb luck, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just gotta upgrade.  For me I had to upgrade the following in App build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
```

Then you will sync your files.  When you run you will get a new issue of installation failed pop up boxes.  Just cancel those and do the following:

```
1) Build -> Clean Project
2) Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s)
3) Run your project! Should work!
```

Follow this [link](https://github.com/fletchy95/Agrivolution/issues/36) if you want any other details on how I solved it but this should do the trick!