# Error : Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-coordinatorlayout

I am getting the following error while building the project. haven't used CoordinatorLayout in this project. just added as a dependency in build.gradle :

I am using Android Studio 3.2 Canary 4.

**LogCat**

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
>   :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /windows/Other/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar, /windows/Other/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1.jar, /windows/Other/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, 
>    .
>   .
>   ...................
>
> /windows/Other/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/294.jar
>
> Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dagkot"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"435e9075f348868c2714fe7c6895efa5\""
        }
        debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/\""
        buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"xxxx\""
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"


    // Dagger dependencies
    compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"

    //Butterknife dependencies
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    // Architecture Components Dependencies
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.lifeCycle"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.lifeCycle"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:$rootProject.lifeCycle"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

    // Retrofit/RxJava Dependencies
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxAndroidVersion"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-kotlin:2.1.1'

    // GSON
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gsonVersion"

    // Rx Location Manager
    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'
    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:rx:3.3.1'

    //Anko Dependencies
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$rootProject.anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$rootProject.anko_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

    implementation("com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:3.1.0") {
        // if you don't use android.app.Fragment you can exclude support for them
        exclude module: "support-v13"
    }
    kapt "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:3.1.0"
}
```

Comment: just add **implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'** in gradle file

Comment: @TusharLathiya I have a similar problem but downgrading has worked for me. I am using version 27.0.0

Comment: If you ever had installed firebase-ui in app dependency, this can occur.. I spent hell a lot of time to figure this out! I never need firebase-ui as i was using picasso to retrieve images from firebase storage.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

It worked when I downgrade the support `appcompat` gradle dependency, like follwing :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

previously it was

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

**OR**

Also this can be fixed by just ***adding support design dependency***
of version 27.1.0 or above to your app level `build.gradle` as following :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

Comment: Once they publish new versions, they make us crazy because of weird errors. :|

Comment: Actually it was pretty opposite in my case. `27.0.x` was failing, while bumping to `27.1.0` made project compile... meh...

Comment: change it to `compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'` in the new versions

Comment: @AnkitMehta I have a similar problem and downgrading hasn't worked for me.

Comment: try adding support design dependency.

Comment: Add the design dependency and cleaning/rebuilding the project might help if it doesn't fix the issue immediately. That's what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solves my issue, i simply up date my compileSDK version to 27 and other dependencies.

Comment: Hi,
Can you please help me out as i used this library for adding Image in PDF
https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/issues/219
 and i am getting this error 
Program type already present: org.spongycastle.cert.AttributeCertificateHolder

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 78):

I faced the same problem, 
I added android support design dependencies to the app level `build.gradle`

**Add following:**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

in build.gradle. Now its working for me.

Comment: Works for me. This problem occurred after a library started to use 27.1.0 while the app was still using 26.x.x.

Comment: Cleaning/rebuilding the project might help if it doesn't fix the issue immediately. That's what worked for me.

Comment: Mostly such errors occured due to version incompatibility. If using appcompat, design libraries better to use latest versions.      

Example :
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

Comment: Hi,
Can you please help me out as i used this library for adding Image in PDF
https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/issues/219
 and i am getting this error 
Program type already present: org.spongycastle.cert.AttributeCertificateHolder

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: use `./gradlew -q yourApp:dependencies --configuration debugRuntimeClasspath` to check duplicate dependencies. Make sure not depend on one lib with different versions.

Answer (score 32):

It might be cause of a library, I faced it because of Glide.

It was

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```

So I added `exclude group: "com.android.support"` And it becomes

```
implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1') {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
```

Comment: I have added this line to all 3 of my dependencies i have used. It resolved my error. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure these two are the same version in your app level build.gradle file

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

I think that should solve the problem

Answer (score 12):

Use the latest `supportLibrary`, version `27.1.1` to solve the problem. worked for me. (many bug fixes included - [see changelog](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-1-1))

Comment: I'm still facing some erros like: `Error:Program type already present: org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpEntityDigester`

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0 add this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112190/error-program-type-already-present-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorl/49155448

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I add the following line to my app/build.gradle:

```
implementation "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
```

With this syntax, version is dynamical.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Don't use like

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
```

It may give you an error and don't use an older version than this.

or event don't do like this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

etc... numbers of libraries and then

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
```

the same library but it has a different version, it can give you an error.

Answer (score 6):

I m using android studio 3.0 
and i upgrade the design pattern dependency from 26.0.1 to 27.1.1 and the error is gone now.

**Add Following in gradle**
`implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`

Answer (score 5):

**I downgrade the support**

```
previously it was
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

**Use it**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

**Its Working Happy Codng**

Comment: Seems more like an upgrade if you go from 27.0.2 to 27.1.0

Answer (score 4):

## Important Update

Android support libraries will not be updated after `28.0.0`. According to [Support Library Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions) -

> This will be the last feature release under the android.support
>   packaging, and developers are encouraged to [migrate to AndroidX 1.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563).

So use [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/) support libraries instead. In your case design library is now available in material package.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' // instead of design
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' // instead of support-v7
}
```

I have put latest versions in dependency, you can [check latest version](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) here at read time.

Useful Posts :

1. [AndroidX introduction & integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563)
2. [Learn about Jetifier (engine behind AndroidX migration)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52518822/6891563)
3. [Some Do's and Dont's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52555981/6891563)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too; and i resolved that in this way:

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '26.0.1'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

be careful my min SDk was 26 , you have to change it with yours!

Answer (score 2):

"Program type already exists"
Remove your /build directory contents, it has some Dex(?) problem with the generated binary files. Got to those answers just like you, they helped to resolve this problem but created many others. Build contents removal works for all.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late answer but I had the same problem and my solution was just adding `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0` or any above support design libraries !!

Answer (score 1):

This can happens when one library is loaded into gradle several times. Most often through other connected libraries.

**Remove a implementation** this library in **build.gradle**

Then **Build** -> **Clear project**

and you can run the assembly)

Answer (score 0):

As android latest update doesn't support 'compile' keyword use 'implementation' in place inside your module **build.gradle** file.

And check thoroughly in build.gradle for dependancy with **+** sign like this.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.+'
```

If there are any dependencies like this, just update them with a specific version.
After that:

1. Sync gradle.
2. Clean your project.
3. Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the answers mentioned here doesn't work then go to File > Invalidate Catches/Restart

Comment: it doesn´t help :(

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is that remove this following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

put general dependencies as:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'    
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to **project's** `gradle.properties` fixed it for us:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your build script should match with application build.gradle dependencies.

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }


dependencies {
    .................
    ...................

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    ................
    ...........
}
```

if you want to downgrade dependencies then also downgrade supportLibVersion and buildToolsVersion .

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem.
But then I realised that the versions I am using of support libraries was not same.

Once I made it same, the error gone.

In your case

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

are not same, so you just downgraded appcompat to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

hence, your problem solved.

But you could also have solved if you could have upgraded support design version to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory where you put additional libraries and delete duplicated libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Changed all dependencies to compile rather than implementation, then I rebuild the project without errors. Then I switched back to implementation rather than leaving it as compile.