# AAPT2 error: check logs for details(Build failed)

Tags: android, gradle, build

I just backed to my old project as I have been along time didn't work on it and I found a lot of errors as a build error in gradle as I use the compile instead implementation and many other process I tried to solve this error a lot but I failed [as this my window error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cngP8.png) that's I couldn't recognize as I used also old Libraries from github

this is myGradle (build.gradle(Project:Waiterer))

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation project(':jtds-1.3.1')
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation project(':librarySV')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.3.9'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1"
}
```

and this my first gradle library I use
build.gradle(Module:library)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

and this is my second library I use
build.gradle(Module:librarySV)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.1'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.4.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}

publish {
    userOrg = 'miguelcatalan'
    groupId = 'com.miguelcatalan'
    artifactId = 'materialsearchview'
    publishVersion = '1.4.0'
    desc = 'Cute library to implement SearchView in a Material Design Approach'
    website = 'https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView'
}
```

hope this could be clear enough If any some thing not clear tell me
Note that: I am not using API I use JDBC JTDS Connection to retrieve data from data base

Comment: This is sadly not enough information. Do you have your project on github? If you can't share your project then go to your project's directory and run "gradlew clean assembleDebug" and edit the post to include the output. It should contain the error from AAPT2

Comment: Thanks a lot @Izabela Orlowska I share the proj on GutHub and I'll send to you

Comment: Sounds good :) it's probably some small adjustment that's needed since AAPT2 is much stricter than AAPT1 and catches most bugs early on instead of allowing runtime issues

Comment: There's an error extracting the files. Can you zip it instead? Or put on bitbucket/github so I can see the sources (dropbox won't show me the content of some files)

Comment: it's already zipped I'll try to but it inside bitbucket/github

Comment: Thanks I was able to extract it properly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem is with the AndroidManifest in your app module:

```
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
        <service
            android:name="SoftKeyboard"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
            tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.view.im"
                android:resource="@xml/method" />
        </service>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element) the 'service' element must be nested under 'application' not 'activity'. So change that part of code to:

```
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name="SoftKeyboard"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.view.im"
            android:resource="@xml/method" />
    </service>
```

This will fix the error you are getting from AAPT2. For your project to build successfully you will also need to update your dependencies as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112190/error-program-type-already-present-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorl). If you do both, everything should build correctly. :)

Comment: Thanks  a lot I found service error but I didn't recognize that there's server's syntax... it worked now!!! it's fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Thing is developers are not comfortable to new AS still. Way of showing error is changed (is weird now).

**First** scroll to down in build errors. If you see an error, click to expand it. It will show you error most probably.

[image]

**Second** If that does not work (like i faced in data binding, where no errors were shown)

Then try build with debug or stacktrace

Go to

> File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler

add like this (add `--stacktrace` or `--debug`), it will log the exceptions. You can see what is causing issue.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Great explanation! I'd just like to add that in the first picture where you see the Build window there's a green hammer icon and under it there's an icon to change the view from bullets to the actual build log. That toggle icon is where the most useful information is hidden.