# What is Jetifier?

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

What is Jetifier? For example, to create a new project using the androidx-packaged dependencies, this new project needs to add the following line to the *gradle.properties* file:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

So what does it mean - "enable jetifier"?

Comment: IIRC, Jetifier is an undocumented bit of Googly technology that is supposed to automatically convert transitive dependencies to use AndroidX libraries. For example, suppose that you have `implementation "com.commonsware.cwac:document:0.3.0"` in your `dependencies`. That library version has a transitive dependency on `com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2`. However, you want to be using `androidx.annotation:annotation` as part of using other AndroidX dependencies. Jetifier would somehow update `com.commonsware.cwac:document` to use `androidx.annotation:annotation`.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This year's Google I/O (18), Google has announced Jetpack which is set/collection of libraries to make developer's life easier.

Jetpack includes previously introduced Android architecture components (ViewModel, Room, Paging, LiveData etc.) as well as newly introduced architecture components like WorkManager, Navigation. Apart from this Jetpack also has other set of libraries like AndroidX, AndroidKTX etc.

AndroidX is new package structure for Android support libraries like support, databinding, design etc.

e.g. now on wards developers will use **androidx.databinding.** instead of **android.databinding.** while importing libraries in our projects

This enables Google to add **SemVer** or **Semantic Versioning** in there library packages. For developers, this means we don't have to use same support library version for all support libraries. Every support or better to say AndroidX library  will maintain its own versioning.

Another advantages for developers is that we don't have to care about maintaining same version for all support library in our project.

About Jetifier, it converts all support package of dependency at build time.
As per official documentation of Jetifier

> Jetifier tool migrates support-library-dependent libraries to rely on
>   the equivalent AndroidX packages instead. The tool lets you migrate an
>   individual library directly, instead of using the Android gradle
>   plugin bundled with Android Studio.

To use AndroidX in a project we have to set targetSdkVersion for our project to **28** and add following 2 lines in **gradle.properties** file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

I hope this will answer your query.

**EDIT**

[This link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor) has mapping of all support library component with their AndroidX counter part.

Also please refer [This](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html) blog for detailed explanation about AndroidX

Comment: You're not really answering the question "What is Jetifier?", just taking about AndroidX and Jetpack.

Comment: @DavidMiguel I have provided answer to main question asked which is what does it mean - "enable jetifier"?. Although if you think my answer is partial, I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 112):

Assuming that you are familiar with `AndroidX`. If not, please see @[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563).

> `Jetifier` will convert `support libraries` of all your dependencies
>   to `AndroidX` automatically, if you don't set it to `true` then your
>   project will have both, the support ([got deprecated after 28.0.0
>   version](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions)) and [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/) package, which is redundant.

#### *For Example*

If you have `PhotoView.java` in your dependency. That uses support library `AppCompatImageView`.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
```

This class is moved now to `androidx` package, so how will `PhotoView` get androidx `AppCompatImageView`? And app still runs in device.

***Who made this run ?***

> **Jetifier**, which converts all support package of dependency at build time.

Jetifier will convert `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` to `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView` while building the project.

#### *Conclusion*

**Enabling Jetifier is important when you migrate from [Support Libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/) to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-overview)**.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563) to understand more about AndroidX.

#### Info

Your code may show compile time errors after enabling Jetifier while using dependency classes.
which you can remove by deleting `.idea`, `.gradle` and re-sync project.

[image: image2]

[image: image1]

Comment: You can get rid of the compile-time errors by deleting .idea/libraries and re-syncing Gradle.

Comment: I think Jetifier works at build time and not at runtime as mentioned here. You can either use android.enableJetifier=true on gradle or use the standalone jetifier tool https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier to migrate to androidx. Both these options replace package names at build time so the old support libraries are not even part of the packaging.

Comment: This is the best answer. +1

Answer (score 14):

**Jetifier** helps in migrating an android project to **AndroidX**.

**Jetifier** helps in making **3rd party** library **compatible** with your AndroidX project.

If you're not using any 3rd party library in your android project, then you don't need to use Jetifier because Jetifier helps only in "making 3rd party library" compatible with your project in case you're migrating to AndroidX. So to make your project use Jetifier, you write below code in **gradle.properties**.

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

If you're not migrating to AndroidX and using the previous way of using Android libraries(e.g: **com.android.support**), then these 3rd party libraries need not be made compatible as these 3rd party libraries are already compatible with the previous way of using Android libraries. In that case, you don't need to use Jetifier, So now, you don't need to write lines given above or you can simply write as below to change the values in future to move to androidx:-

```
android.enableJetifier=false
android.useAndroidX=false
```

Answer (score 7):

**Jetifier**

From [official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx#using_androidx_libraries_in_your_project)

> When this flag is set to true, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX dependencies by rewriting their binaries. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.

It is useful for compatibility. When a Consumer uses `androidX` and a Producer uses `support`. For example when your project on `AndroidX` wants to use a dependency which uses `support library` instead of `AndroidX`[<sup>[Example]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557383/4770877)

Answer (score 5):

**Jetifier**

The [**jetifier**](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) is a handy tool that automatically migrates your `dependencies` to `AndroidX` at build time. Without it, you'd need every dependency you use to have an AndroidX version before you can migrate, and that probably won't happen for some time.

There's an important limitation to note: the jetifier only works on packaged artifacts. It does not work on your source code, which you are expected to update yourself

for enabling AndroidX, you need to add 2 flags to your `gradle.properties` file. The first flag tells the Android Plugin to use `AndroidX` packages instead of `AppCompat`, and the second flag will enable the `Jetifier` :

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280090/what-is-androidx/52517772), [this](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/converting-your-android-app-to-jetpack-85aecfce34d3) post to understand more about AndroidX