# Refactor from Support Libraries to AndroidX with dependencies

Tags: android, androidx

I'd like to migrate my app from using Android Support Libraries to AndroidX components.

This is my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    /*
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2"
    */
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01"

    implementation 'com.dmitrymalkovich.android:progress-fab:1.6'
    implementation 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.2.0'

}
```

In the dependencies section you can see the old dependencies as comment. 
With the AndroidX dependencies I got the following error while building the app:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: duplicate value for resource \u0027attr/behavior_peekHeight\u0027 with config \u0027\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/plinzen/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-1.0.0-beta01.aar/5f1c73d5e36b65b3011573345597f31d/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":1303,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":70911,"endColumn":68,"endOffset":70975}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource previously defined here.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/plinzen/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-1.0.0-beta01.aar/5f1c73d5e36b65b3011573345597f31d/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":1303,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":70911,"endColumn":68,"endOffset":70975}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
```

I assume it might be some kind of collision with my other two dependencies since both are still using the Android Support Libraries, like `./gradlew app:dependencies` states:

```
implementation 'com.dmitrymalkovich.android:progress-fab:1.6'
implementation 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.2.0'



+--- com.dmitrymalkovich.android:progress-fab:1.6
|    \--- com.android.support:design:23.3.0
|         +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0 -> 27.0.1
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.1
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.1
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1
|         |    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0
|         |    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0
|         |    |              \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.1
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.1 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.1
|         |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1
|         |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.1 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.1 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.1
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.1 (*)
|         |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.1
|         |         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.1 (*)
|         |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0 -> 27.0.1
|         \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0
|              +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0 (*)
|              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0 -> 27.0.1
\--- cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.2.0
     \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1 (*)
```

Is there a way to solve my issue?

Can I simply exclude the (sub-) dependencies in my `build.gradle`? I have some doubts, because the package names are different between AndroidX and Android Support.

Edit: I enabled Jetifier in my project `gradle.properties` like suggested by Commonsware, but I still got the same error:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: In theory, the Jetifier is supposed to help here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51680671/115145

Comment: Ok, I didn't enable Jetifier up to now. I'll give it a try and report! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not recognize that AndroidX requires `Android Studio 3.2` as minimum version. I was still working on `Android Studio 3.1`, that's why the Jetifier was not working. After that my code compiles.