# Injecting Androidx Fragments using Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I want to inject my Androidx fragments using dagger 2. In my activity I have:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HasSupportFragmentInjector
{
    @Inject Repository repository;
    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<androidx.fragment.app.Fragment> dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
       
    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<androidx.fragment.app.Fragment> supportFragmentInjector()
    {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

the problem is when i want to build the project i get this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol class MapBuilder
```

and when i change **androidx.fragment.app.Fragment** to **Fragment** in DispatchingAndroidInjector i don't get this error any more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Androidx is not supported yet, but enabling jetifier may solve your problem.

Just add the below code to your `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Also see these issues for detail:

- [migration to androidx library](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1181)
- [AndroidInjection support for androidx Fragment](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1217)

Comment: thank you for your answer. it worked, but i had to upgrade dagger to 2.16 version .

Comment: It still doesn't accept android x Fragment even if I enable jetifier Dagger version 2.19

Comment: I'm using Dagger 2.21 with androidx and it works but you have to use `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)` as @cherif mentioned below.

Answer (score 15):

The following worked for me:

First, add gradle dependency the dagger for support library:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.23.2"
```

Then in your fragment which is the child of **androidx.fragment** inject in the following way:

```
AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
```

Answer (score 10):

Dagger supports were missing for AndroidX. It is added for version 2.21 and above

So you can use it as -

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.21'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.21'
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.21"
```

Apart from this, if you are using for first time and migrating from support to AndroidX, you will also need to take care in `gradle.properties` as @Saeed Masoumi mentioned. You need to add following -

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Jetifier will help you to migrate from **support** libraries to **AndroidX** packages at run time. Best answer you can find for that over here -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52002285/842607

Comment: Since you are commenting now, have you tried koin? If you are using Kotlin, and require to inject, compare Koin vs Dagger and use. https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin

Comment: @jimt patel yes i tried it. Was stuck since two days and now it's resolved.  Thanks!

Comment: yeah i'm using kotlin and sure will try koin.

Answer (score 4):

as was suggested before, add the below code to your gradle.properties

> android.useAndroidX=true
>   android.enableJetifier=true

And if you are trying to inject into a Fragment you have to replace `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` with `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)`

Answer (score 2):

If **jetifier** does not change s**upport packages** to **androidx** packages. You can download `jetifier` tool from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) and convert the **android-dagger-support.aar** file manually by using the following command.

```
./jetifier-standalone -i dagger-android-support-<version>.aar -o <output-name>
```

Then add the library to your project. This is the **HasSupportFragment** class after conversion

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import dagger.android.AndroidInjector;

public interface HasSupportFragmentInjector {
    AndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector();
}
```

> Somehow, jetifier tool was not converting libraries in AndroidStudio.
>   I had to do it manually.