# dagger android support to androidx.fragment

Tags: dagger-2, androidx, dagger

How to inject a fragment from the package ***androidx.fragment.app.Fragment*** ?

I'm using the [dagger-android](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) framework to inject my dependencies in my code.

As the documentation says I do this to inject my fragment

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // ...
}
```

the problem is that **AndroidSupportInjection** class accept only fragments of the package android.support.v4.app.Fragment or if I use **AndroidInjection** class only accept fragments of the package android.app.Fragment and I want to use fragments of the androidx.fragment.app.Fragment package.

Also DaggerFrament extend from ***android.support.v4.app.Fragment*** and want to use a fragment from androidx

And If I try to implement ***HasSupportFragmentInjector*** also this interface use a fragment from android.support

Comment: You should switch `android.support.*` artifacts to `androidx.*` and declare `useAndroidX` and `enableJetifier` in your gradle file. See here for general reference: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-overview

Comment: Ran into the same issue after I switched to androidx namespace to try it out. Have not been able to resolve it.

Comment: @Irving Did you get solution ?

Comment: no yet, for now I move to use android.support.* packages classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Injecting Androidx Fragments using Dagger 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827692/injecting-androidx-fragments-using-dagger-2)

Answer (score 9):

add the below code to your gradle.properties

> android.useAndroidX=true
>   android.enableJetifier=true

And if you are trying to inject into a Fragment you have to replace `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` with `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in case of **HasFragmentInjector**. You need to use **HasSupportFragmentInjector** for fragment injection. This is because, `HasFragmentInjector` uses `android.app.Fragment` which is **not effected** by `jetifier`. You need to add `android-dagger-support` library, `jetifier` converts all the support packages to androidx in Studio 3.3 (if `jetifier` is enabled).

If jetifier does not change support packages to androidx packages. You can download `jetifier` tool from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) and convert the **android-dagger-support.aar** file manually by using the following command.

```
./jetifier-standalone -i dagger-android-support-<version>.aar -o <output-name>
```

Then add the library to your project. This is the **HasSupportFragment** class after conversion

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import dagger.android.AndroidInjector;

public interface HasSupportFragmentInjector {
    AndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector();
}
```

> Somehow, jetifier tool was not converting libraries in AndroidStudio.
>   I had to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and it was due to the Dagger version. On version 2.17 there is an strange issue, but if you roll back to version 2.16 it compiles perfectly (apart from the flags on gradle.properties that Paul posted).

From there using the tutorials you won't have trouble. Forgot to mention that on my project I had the non-androidX version of everything, then I ran the androidX migration that android studio offers, and after that I had to switch the Dagger version, but I suppose that if you do it from the start it's the same.

Hope this helps, if you switch and it doesn't work, post a little bit of your dagger implementation and plugins versions and I will try to help more!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = true
```

Comment: This option didn't help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference. i had the same problem. It was Jetifier issue. please upgrade your gradle build tools plugin to 3.3.0

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

Sample code: https://github.com/jega-ms/android-dagger2-mvp-rx

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to work with `androidx` namespace for Dagger 2.21

1. Downloaded the `jetifier` tool from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier
2. Unzip into a folder and open a terminal pointing into the extracted `bin` folder
3. From Android Studio, open a class like `DaggerFragment` to check the path where the file is stored, for me (in MacOS) is something like this:
   [image]
4. From terminal execute this command (replacing with the correct variables and path)

   `./jetifier-standalone -i /Users/{YOUR_USER}/.gradle/caches/{PATH_TO_DAGGER_ANDROID_SUPPORT_FOLDER}/dagger-android-support-2.21.aar -o dagger-android-support-2.21.aar`

   The converted `dagger-android-support-2.21.aar` will appear in your `bin` folder
5. Now open your app `build.gradle` file and change this line
   `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])`
   adding the `, '*.aar'` part in the include array
6. Move the generated `dagger-android-support-2.21.aar` from `bin` to `libs` folder inside your project.
7. Remove (or comment) this line from the dependencies
   `implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.21`

   Now you can proceed invalidating the cache and rebuild the project and now `DaggerFragment` will point to your converted version which uses `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`

> NOTE: Obviously this is a temporary workaround and you should move to the official version as soon this is fixed in Dagger

Comment: Do you still need to add library manually if you directly update it in gradle cache?

Comment: I tried replacing the aar directly in the cache folder but it didn't work for me. Only referencing from the libs folder is the safe way to do this

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my particular problem was to use android dagger classes as interfaces instead of extend of them:

```
class MyFragment() : HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var childFragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
        return childFragmentInjector
    }

........

}
```

To my Activities

```
class MyActivity : HasSupportFragmentInjector {
    @Inject
    internal lateinit var fragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> = fragmentInjector
```

......
    }

and also I have this in my gradle.properties file:

android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = true