# androidx and support dependency causing multidex error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-multidex, androidx

I have a library project which is using `androidx` dependency in it.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'
```

After adding library project in my app, i am getting multiple errors related to `dexMerger` , `MultiDex` , `Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/...`
.

So i searched for that file by using `window+O` (Navigate --> Class). Then i found that same class is used in `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'` and `android.support.v4..` libraries . So I tried to exclude like below -

```
    implementation('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01') {
         exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Also i have added `multidex true` but nothing helped. I read about `AndroidX` looks like it contains many classes that are similar to support libraries. What should be done in this case ? I have latest version of Android Studio and my `compileSdkVersion` is `28`. My all dependencies are up to date.
I have already added `multidex` dependency and my application class is also extending `MultiDexApplication`.

Comment: Maybe enabling Jetifier will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680671/what-is-jetifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Following Command to check which dependency has duplicate class

**./gradlew app:dependencies**

Then Exclude the module like this

```
{
  exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem!
Let me know if you have any issues!

Comment: Thanks ! excluding `com.android.support` removed error

Answer (score 1):

Just setting the `multidex true` is not enough.

You need to include this dependency first

`implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`

then

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

then in ur manifest

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
</application>
```

Comment: I have already added `multidex` dependency and my application class is also extending `MultiDexApplication`. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this before. No Luck !!