# Can Android X Projects use library modules that are using support-library dependencies?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

Let's say i have a public library module published to Maven Central and it is using the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Will this library work with no problems on Android X based projects?

Comment: no, You should not use the com.android.support and android x dependencies in your app at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has released a tool called [Jetifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680671/what-is-jetifier) which migrates support-library-dependent libraries to rely on the equivalent AndroidX packages instead, so your libiary should work when Jetifier is enabled.

To enable Jetifier, make sure `compileSdkVersion` is set to API 28 or above and add the following lines in **gradle.properties**:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Nice! So you mean i should tell my library users to add "enableJetifier=true" to their app gradle.properties if they are using Android X. That way my library can work for everyone. What happens if i make my library using Android X? There is no way for someone using support-library to use it, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. AndroidX should not be used with support-library, so if you are using AndroidX then these support library user may not be able to use your library.

Comment: Accepting answer