# Jetifier does not convert support dependencies

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-jetifier

I cloned [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) locally and added the modules to my existing project using my `settings.gradle` as described in the documentation:

```
gradle.ext.exoplayerRoot = 'path/to/exoplayer'
gradle.ext.exoplayerModulePrefix = 'exoplayer-'
apply from: new File(gradle.ext.exoplayerRoot, 'core_settings.gradle')
```

Whenever I try to build the project, I receive the following build error:

> error: package android.support.annotation does not exist

These happen for all `@NonNull` and `@Nullable` annotations in the **ExoPlayer modules**.

I created a new project in Android Studio 3.2.1, added AndroidX support in my `gradle.properties` file and updated my `build.gradle` file accordingly.

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //ExoPlayer
    implementation project(':exoplayer-library-core')
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.databinding.enableV2=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

If I understand correctly, [Jetifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680671/what-is-jetifier/52518822#52518822) should be able to resolve and convert the support dependencies to AndroidX dependencies, but this does not seem to be the case for these local modules.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the issue by specifying a `gradle.properties` file for every local exoplayer module in my project that is used in the application. I still don't know what causes the issue, but preventing Jetifier from **migrating to AndroidX** for the local modules seems to solve this issue.

```
# Local module Gradle settings.
android.useAndroidX=false
# Jetifier will convert support libraries of all your dependencies to AndroidX automatically,
# if you don't set it true then your project will have both support
android.enableJetifier=false
```