# troubleshooting debug problems in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I experienced a problem in this section `Could not determine the dependencies of task': app: compileProfileJavaWithJavac`
I have searched various sources but have not found a solution, and I use the flutter framework.

I have tried various ways such as searching for references related to my problem, but I did not find a solution, either on github, stackoverflow and also flutter.

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileProfileJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:profileCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not find androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:28.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

You have to migrate to AndroidX.

Go to your android/gradle.properties and add this line of code:

> android.useAndroidX=true

This will make sure to use the AndroidX library instead of the Support library.

EDIT:

You may also want to add `android.enableJetifier=true` which enables you the Jetifier, i.e: a set/collection of libraries to make developer's life easier. For more info. look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680671/what-is-jetifier).

Comment: I have added the second but it still shows the same problem, about the core problem, huh
please give instructions

Comment: Have you added `android.useAndroidX = true` ?

Comment: android.useAndroidX = true and android.enableJetifier = true,I have added

Comment: Did you get another error by adding those lines, if yes please provide us with the stacktrace

Comment: even strange when I delete
android.useAndroidX = true and android.enableJetifier = true
the error is even reduced by one

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgXAE.png


I just tried to make a question on stackoverflow, please understand if my method of displaying images is not good

Comment: #newbie99
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgXAE.png


I just tried to make a question on stackoverflow, please understand if my method of displaying images is not good

Comment: In your terminal please run `flutter doctor` and send us the result

Comment: @rahmadiqbal go in your build.gradle and if you don't have `google()` in your repository, add it.. like this `buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }`

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.8.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393], locale id-ID)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

Comment: @rahmadiqbal Try and add the `google()` in your build.gradle repository

Comment: in allprojects??

Comment: I've added it,   



allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Last thing I can do is to check you pubspec.yaml and both build.gradles. Send picture of them

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiGEV.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lT5j.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K61TO.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/43fiz.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J026.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyWbE.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQokg.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP8yk.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/75E1E.png

Comment: this is my capture

Comment: You got some errors in the build.gradle file, did you try to fix those first?

Comment: tell me how to fix it?