# Gradle Error: '(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory)' cannot be applied to '(com.fstyle.library.helper.AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory)'

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, androidx, android-jetifier

I'm using the AssetSQLiteOpenHelper library on an Android application but when creating a new instance of the `AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory` class in the following context:

```
RoomDatabase.Builder<AppDatabase> builder = Room.databaseBuilder(
    context.getApplicationContext(), 
    AppDatabase.class,context.getString(R.string.database_name));

return (builder.openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
    .allowMainThreadQueries()
    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build());
```

I receive the error:

```
'openHelperFactory(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory)' in 
'androidx.room.RoomDatabase.Builder' cannot be applied to 
'(com.fstyle.library.helper.AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory)'
```

This is contrary to what the documentation states([click here](https://github.com/daolq3012/AssetSQLiteOpenHelper) to view their documentation).

I have made sure to include their dependency in the `build.gradle` file via:

```
implementation 'com.github.daolq3012:AssetSQLiteOpenHelper:V1.0.1'
```

I have tried 'Clean Project' -> 'Rebuild Project' and the 'Invalidate caches/Restart` options with no success.

Keep in mind I am answering this question myself as I have found a solution and want to share it with anyone else who might run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following lines to the `gradle.properties` file then syncing the project with the Gradle files solved this problem:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I think this error was caused by migration issues when migrating from [Support Libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library) to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx), therefore enabling Jetifier resolved it.

Here is a link to a helpful SO answer on what `android.enableJetifier=true` does: [android - What is Jetifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52518822/10871450)