# Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DownloadNotificationHelper

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

Having this error while i was trying to run my flutter application:

> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DownloadNotificationHelper found in modules jetified-exoplayer-core-2.17.0-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.17.0) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.15.0-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.15.0)

> Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 1m 47s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

How can I fix this error.?
Below are my build.gradle files:

**app\build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.college_club"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**android\build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Try disabling jetifier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680671/what-is-jetifier

Comment: @Blundell tried, still same error

Comment: Hmm not sure how you can get a jettifier error if jettifying is turned off? :-) unless you are directly depending on two jettified libraries?

Comment: Getting exactly the same error after updating to Kotlin `'1.6.10'`. Have you found any solutions ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Fixed it by adding below line in `/android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.17.0')
}
```

Comment: Adding this line solves the problem but in this case I have errors in Flutter with `assets_audio_player` package.

Comment: Hey @shuster that's unfortunate. Check this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100948 it may assist you.

Comment: It's related my issue, thanks. But still it didn't solve my problem. I will move to another package.

Answer (score 3):

- Try to reinstall the flutter libraries using the following commands,

  ```
  flutter clean
  flutter pub cache clean
  flutter pub get
  ```
- Add the following implementation on the app-level `build.gradle` file

  ```
  dependencies {
     ....
     implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.17.0')
  }
  ```
- Ensure that the `androidX` and `Jetifier` support is enabled and mentioned in the `gradle.properties` file. If not, add the following entries to the `gradle.properties` file.

  ```
  android.useAndroidX=true
  android.enableJetifier=true
  ```
- You can implement the following dependency in the `build.gradle` file if none of the above steps resolved your issue.

  ```
  implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
  ```

Answer (score 2):

if you use EXPO check if you have installed any expo module also using exoplayer to avoid version conflict.

In my I was using expo-av and when I wanted to add react-native-track-player I had the same problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try to clean all caches and get dependencies again:

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub cache clean`
- `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update these two files

*build.gradle file*

```
...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0' -- update 4.1.0 to 7.1.1
...
}
```

*gradle-wrapper.properties file*

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip  -- update 6.5 to 7.2
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you have to make sure your gradle in your build.gradle and the gradle in your android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties are the same version.

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
```

and

android/build.gradle

```
dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1' ... }
```

find last gradle version
https://gradle.org/releases/

find last dependency version
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google

After apply these changes, if you use useProguard, so you should face issue like:
useProguard not found or etc
The useProguard option was removed since gradle 7.0.0, so you should delete this line in your_project/android/app/build.gradle