# How to import .jar file in module and also in application?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have one project (MyProject) in which there is one library(customlib) module is there, that library module is using one jar file commontask.jar which i imported int module. i also want to use same jar file in android project. I imported that module(customlib) in MyProject but if i tried to access class(CustomActivity.java) of custom lib then it  giving error can not access CustomActivity.java.

customlib gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/customtask.jar')
}
```

Myproject gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':customlib')
}
```

if i import that customtask.jar in that project, and when i generate apk its giving error

```
Program type already present: com.task.common.Helper
```

Comment: Did you check this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49112190/5180017)?

Answer (score 4):

**Original Question (Before Update)**

*How to import .jar file in module and also in android application?*

**Answer:**

- For .**jar files** you can add them in app folder of Android Studio Project
- Then Open you Android Studio Project as Project View and inside app folder, Right click on jar file and select add as library.

---

**1. Open Android Studio in Project View**

[image]

**2. Open app >> create libs package by right clicking on app. add you .jar file inside libs.**

[image]

**3. Then right click on your .jar file and add it as library**

[image]

Comment: i put it there then its giving this error while building apk
Program type already present: com.task.common.Helper

Comment: Have you followed above method ?

Comment: yes but not able to access .jar file class into my application

Comment: what is problem accessing it ? If it is imported as Library , you can use it

Comment: @AliAhmed i followed the steps, but all the files are still not accessible. Errors are "Cannot resolve symbol".