# Gradle: Error: Program type already present: javax.inject.Inject

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm pretty new to Android Studios and Gradle, so if this question is something obvious I'd like to apologize.

I get the following error with the given code:

`Error: Program type already present: javax.inject.Inject`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xxx.cryptoapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.lucadev:coinmarketcap-api:2.1'
}
```

I hope you can help me out. :)

**Edit**

I looked into the dependencies and saw that `javax.inject` is used two times:

```
//short version of the list
+--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b42@jar
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.4@jar
    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1@jar
```

However I can't quite understand how I exclude the correct module..

Comment: can you post the full stracktrace?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112190/error-program-type-already-present-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorl  you need to check dependencies. There might be some conflict. or else write exclusion policy on modules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Program type already present" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean)

Comment: (One way to make a quote stand out is to use not apostrophes, but `\`\`` "backticks" like `Error: Program type already present: javax.inject.Inject`. The other is to put it in a separate line and prefix it with `> ` (or use the "quote button" in the post editor).)

Comment: I tried adding the support dependency `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` but without success..

Comment: I found out what the problem seems to be, thanks @Killer - However javax.inject seems to be used by two dependencies and i want to exclude it from one, but I don't know where it comes from.

    `+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.4@jar<br/>
    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1@jar`

Answer (score 0):

assuming this is coming from a `.jar` file in the `libs` directory; it can be excluded alike this:

```
implementation (fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])) {
    exclude group: "javax.inject", module: "javax.inject"
}
```

while actually, the `.jar` should probably be just deleted and replaced with:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
implementation ("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8") {
    exclude group: "javax.inject", module: "javax.inject"
}
```

the repository for this is `mavenCentral()`.

Comment: Your first suggestion throws as follows: `Gradle sync failed: Could not find method exclude() for arguments [{group=javax.inject, module=javax.inject}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultSelfResolvingDependency.
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (266 ms)`

Your second suggestion compiled but I still hat the same error with javax.inject ..