# Android - Error: Program type already present: com.google.gsonhtcfix.Gson$5

Tags: android

I am getting this error while running the project - Program type already present: com.google.gsonhtcfix.Gson$5

Any solution for this?

Other answers in StackOverflow said to add this piece of code but it didn't work for me

```
configurations {
            all*.exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
        }
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation project(':abc')
    'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':xyz')

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency {
                DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                    if (details.requested.group == 'com.myapp.nm') {
                        details.useVersion "1.0.2"
                    }
                    if (details.requested.group == 'com.myapp.utility') {
                        details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe the version matters? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49155448/8034839

Comment: why are you excluding gson

Comment: this `build.gradle` is invalid and those packages do not even depend on `com.google.code.gson`. the duplicate comes from `:abc` or `:xyz` ...