# Program type already present: android.support.compat.R$attr

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-appcompat

My project has two modules i.e. app and moduleX.
app project is mostly built on Java and moduleX is completly in Kotlin.

While creating "debug" build, it's running fine but when I try to create release build i.e. devRelease, it give following error-

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDevRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.compat.R$attr
```

Here is the app level build.gradle-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appname"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner rootProject.ext.testInstrumentationRunner
    }
    flavorDimensions "environment"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "environment"
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }

        qa {
            dimension "environment"
            versionNameSuffix "-test"
            applicationIdSuffix ".test"
        }

        staging {
            dimension "environment"
            versionNameSuffix "-staging"
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        }

        prod {
            dimension "environment"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
        release {
            storeFile file("keystore/appname_keystore.jks")
            storePassword properties.getProperty('storePassword')
            keyAlias properties.getProperty('keyAlias')
            keyPassword properties.getProperty('keyPassword')
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // force certain versions of dependencies (including transitive)
            force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:' + okHttpLibVersion
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //Unit testing
    testImplementation rootProject.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation rootProject.ext.androidTestRunner
    androidTestImplementation rootProject.ext.espresso
    testImplementation rootProject.ext.mockito
    testImplementation rootProject.ext.facebookScreenshotTestCommon
    implementation rootProject.ext.facebookScreenshotTestLitho
    androidTestImplementation rootProject.ext.supportTestRules

    //Support Library & UI
    implementation rootProject.ext.constraintLayout
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportCompatV7
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportDesign
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportCardView
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportCustomTabs
    implementation rootProject.ext.glide
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    // Dagger dependency for DI
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16"
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    // RxJava lib
    implementation rootProject.ext.rxAndroid
    implementation rootProject.ext.rxJava
    implementation rootProject.ext.rxJavaRetrofitAdapter

    //Retrofit
    implementation(rootProject.ext.retrofit) {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation rootProject.ext.okHttp
    implementation rootProject.ext.okHttpLoggingInterceptor
    implementation rootProject.ext.retrofitGsonConverter
    implementation rootProject.ext.retrofitScalarsConverter

    //Memory leaks
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.3'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.3'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-support-fragment:1.6.3'

    //Others
    implementation rootProject.ext.parceler
    annotationProcessor rootProject.ext.parcelerAnnotationProcessor
    implementation rootProject.ext.lombok
    annotationProcessor rootProject.ext.lombokAnnotationProcessor
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinVersion"

    // Fingerprint Auth
    implementation 'com.multidots:fingerprint-auth:1.0.1'

    //Module Projects
    api project(':energyswitchcui')
}

screenshots {
    multipleDevices true
}
```

and here is the build.gradle file of moduleX-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        // need separate runner for facebook screenshot test in module
        testInstrumentationRunner 'com.appname.SnapshotTestRunner'
    }

    flavorDimensions "environment"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "environment"
        }

        qa {
            dimension "environment"
        }

        staging {
            dimension "environment"
        }

        prod {
            dimension "environment"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //Unit testing
    testImplementation rootProject.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation rootProject.ext.androidTestRunner
    androidTestImplementation rootProject.ext.espresso
    testImplementation rootProject.ext.mockito
    testImplementation rootProject.ext.facebookScreenshotTestCommon
    implementation rootProject.ext.facebookScreenshotTestLitho
    androidTestImplementation rootProject.ext.supportTestRules

    //Support Library & UI
    implementation rootProject.ext.constraintLayout
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportCompatV7
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportDesign
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportCardView
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportCustomTabs
    implementation rootProject.ext.glide
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

    // RxJava lib
    implementation rootProject.ext.rxAndroid
    implementation rootProject.ext.rxJava
    implementation rootProject.ext.rxJavaRetrofitAdapter

    //Retrofit
    implementation(rootProject.ext.retrofit) {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation rootProject.ext.okHttp
    implementation rootProject.ext.okHttpLoggingInterceptor
    implementation rootProject.ext.retrofitGsonConverter
    implementation rootProject.ext.retrofitScalarsConverter

    //Others
    implementation rootProject.ext.parceler
    kapt rootProject.ext.parcelerAnnotationProcessor
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinVersion"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// need for facebook screenshot test in module
apply plugin: 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot'
screenshots {
    multipleDevices true
}
```

This is the project level build.gradle file-

```
apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.3.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot:plugin:0.8.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is dependencies.gradle-

```
ext {
    //Android
    minSdkVersion = 24
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    compileSdkVersion = targetSdkVersion
    testInstrumentationRunner = "com.appname.runner.SnapshotTestRunner"
    androidSupportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    okHttpLibVersion = "3.14.0"

    //Unit testing
    junit = "junit:junit:4.12"
    androidTestRunner = "com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2"
    espresso = "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2"
    mockito = "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19"
    facebookScreenshotTestCommon = "com.facebook.testing.screenshot:layout-hierarchy-common:0.8.0"
    facebookScreenshotTestLitho = "com.facebook.testing.screenshot:layout-hierarchy-litho:0.8.0"
    supportTestRules = "com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2"

    //Support Library & UI
    constraintLayout = "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"
    supportCompatV7 = "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$androidSupportLibVersion"
    supportDesign = "com.android.support:design:$androidSupportLibVersion"
    supportCardView = "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$androidSupportLibVersion"
    supportCustomTabs = "com.android.support:customtabs:$androidSupportLibVersion"
    glide = "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0"

    // RxJava lib
    rxAndroid = "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
    rxJava = "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8"
    rxJavaRetrofitAdapter = "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"

    //Retrofit
    retrofit = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
    okHttp = "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpLibVersion"
    okHttpLoggingInterceptor = "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpLibVersion"
    retrofitGsonConverter = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
    retrofitScalarsConverter = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0"

    //Others
    parceler = "org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6"
    parcelerAnnotationProcessor = "org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6"
    lombok = "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"
    lombokAnnotationProcessor = "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"
}
```

I have already tried many answers i.e.
[Error : Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112190/error-program-type-already-present-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorl)

but nothing is working here.

Comment: please also post your project level gradle

Comment: @android Updated the question with more information

Comment: convert your project to androidx and then please try to put "android.dagger-androidx=true" in your gradle.properties

Comment: I converted the project to androidx and started getting same error in the form of androidx i.e.- 
Program type already present: androidx.support.R$attr

Comment: have you put "android.dagger-androidx=true" in gradle.properties?

Comment: No, I removed dagger dependencies and its code that time when I was getting dagger related error.

Comment: no its not only for dagger just try to paste and see its working or not because i had the same issue without using dagger which solved my problem

Comment: ok I'm trying this now.

Comment: Tried this but getting this error-
Program type already present: androidx.core.R$attr

I have added dagger flag also in gradle.properties

Comment: @android is there any other resolution for this?

Comment: i'm trying to solve it. please wait

Comment: @android sure, I'm also trying. Please let me know if you find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have come up with the solution and run successful below gradles with just little version changes:

> Main Project Level Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot:plugin:0.8.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


ext {
    //Android
    minSdkVersion = 24
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    compileSdkVersion = targetSdkVersion
    testInstrumentationRunner = "com.appname.runner.SnapshotTestRunner"
    androidSupportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    androidCompatVersion = "1.0.0-beta01"
    androidCardViewVersion = "1.0.0"
    constraintlayoutVersion = "1.1.3"
    okHttpLibVersion = "3.14.0"

    //Unit testing
    junit = "junit:junit:4.12"
    androidTestRunner = "androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4"
    espresso = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4"
    supportTestRules = "com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2"

    //Support Library & UI
    constraintLayout = "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintlayoutVersion"
    supportCompatV7 = "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidCompatVersion"
    supportDesign = "com.android.support:design:$androidSupportLibVersion"
    supportCardView = "androidx.cardview:cardview:$androidCardViewVersion"
    supportCustomTabs = "com.android.support:customtabs:$androidSupportLibVersion"
    glide = "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0"


    mockito = "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19"
    facebookScreenshotTestCommon = "com.facebook.testing.screenshot:layout-hierarchy-common:0.8.0"
    facebookScreenshotTestLitho = "com.facebook.testing.screenshot:layout-hierarchy-litho:0.8.0"


    // RxJava lib
    rxAndroid = "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
    rxJava = "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8"
    rxJavaRetrofitAdapter = "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"

    //Retrofit
    retrofit = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
    okHttp = "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpLibVersion"
    okHttpLoggingInterceptor = "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpLibVersion"
    retrofitGsonConverter = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
    retrofitScalarsConverter = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0"

    //Others
    parceler = "org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9"
    parcelerAnnotationProcessor = "org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9"
    lombok = "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"
    lombokAnnotationProcessor = "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"

}
```

> App Level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gradletest"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation rootProject.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation rootProject.ext.androidTestRunner
    androidTestImplementation rootProject.ext.espresso
    androidTestImplementation rootProject.ext.supportTestRules
    testImplementation rootProject.ext.mockito
    testImplementation rootProject.ext.facebookScreenshotTestCommon
    implementation rootProject.ext.facebookScreenshotTestLitho
    implementation rootProject.ext.constraintLayout
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportCompatV7
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportDesign
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportCardView
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportCustomTabs
    implementation rootProject.ext.glide
    // RxJava lib
    implementation rootProject.ext.rxAndroid
    implementation rootProject.ext.rxJava
    implementation rootProject.ext.rxJavaRetrofitAdapter
    //Retrofit
    implementation(rootProject.ext.retrofit) {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
        implementation rootProject.ext.okHttp
        implementation rootProject.ext.okHttpLoggingInterceptor
        implementation rootProject.ext.retrofitGsonConverter
        implementation rootProject.ext.retrofitScalarsConverter
    implementation rootProject.ext.parceler
//        annotationProcessor rootProject.ext.parcelerAnnotationProcessor
        implementation rootProject.ext.lombok
        annotationProcessor rootProject.ext.lombokAnnotationProcessor
    //Memory leaks
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.3'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.3'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-support-fragment:1.6.3'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.multidots:fingerprint-auth:1.0.1'
    implementation project(':energyswitchcui')
}
```

> Module("energyswitchcui") gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //Unit testing
    testImplementation rootProject.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation rootProject.ext.androidTestRunner
    androidTestImplementation rootProject.ext.espresso
    testImplementation rootProject.ext.mockito
    testImplementation rootProject.ext.facebookScreenshotTestCommon
    implementation rootProject.ext.facebookScreenshotTestLitho
    androidTestImplementation rootProject.ext.supportTestRules

    //Support Library & UI
    implementation rootProject.ext.constraintLayout
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportCompatV7
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportDesign
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportCardView
    implementation rootProject.ext.supportCustomTabs
    implementation rootProject.ext.glide
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

    // RxJava lib
    implementation rootProject.ext.rxAndroid
    implementation rootProject.ext.rxJava
    implementation rootProject.ext.rxJavaRetrofitAdapter

    //Retrofit
    implementation(rootProject.ext.retrofit) {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation rootProject.ext.okHttp
    implementation rootProject.ext.okHttpLoggingInterceptor
    implementation rootProject.ext.retrofitGsonConverter
    implementation rootProject.ext.retrofitScalarsConverter

    //Others
    implementation rootProject.ext.parceler
//    kapt rootProject.ext.parcelerAnnotationProcessor
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// need for facebook screenshot test in module
apply plugin: 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot'
screenshots {
    multipleDevices true
}
```

Below are the errors that were encountered during gradle and what i have done to solve it:

1) Error: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

Solution: put below lines under android section of app level gradle

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

2) Error: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.

Solution: Removed "annotationProcessor rootProject.ext.parcelerAnnotationProcessor" from app level gradle and updated this library in main level gradle under "ext" section from 1.1.6 to 1.1.9 'parcelerAnnotationProcessor = "org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9"'
but it does not worked

So i removed that library and successfully build gradle and also can run the project. Here is the dropbox link you can find project on :https://www.dropbox.com/s/ki8gpfdaxh0dzo3/GradleTest.zip?dl=0

**3) Above solution will work only in debug mode but in release build we have to also remove this two libraries to build successfully in release build:**

```
facebookScreenshotTestCommon = "com.facebook.testing.screenshot:layout-hierarchy-common:0.9.0"

facebookScreenshotTestLitho = "com.facebook.testing.screenshot:layout-hierarchy-litho:0.9.0"
```

Comment: Made changes in my code, it didn't work. Then downloaded your code from dropbox but it's also not working. It's working in "debug" mode but not in "release" mode. Have you tried it in "release" build?

Comment: No I have not tried in release mode, let me also try in release mode and  I'll update answer as i'll done.

Comment: Sure, the issue is in release build only

Comment: its because of facebookScreenshotTestLitho and if i updated it from 0.8.0 to 0.9.0 but its not working. if i remove "implementation rootProject.ext.facebookScreenshotTestLitho" from app gradle as well from module gradle then it will work in release build also.

Comment: Yeah, not only in Litho, but also in support test rule library.
I have created an issue in facebook GitHub-
https://github.com/facebook/screenshot-tests-for-android/issues/218

Thank you so much for helping me out. Please update your answer then I will mark it as accepted.