# "Program type already present: Android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$1

Tags: java, android, firebase, appodeal

Hello developers, I am facing a problem, I have tried all the answers available on StackOverflow, not able to solve my problem.
initially, it was saying unable to merge dex, after some changes its now showing this error.

Warning: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.

Error:Program type already present: android.support.v7.util.AsyncListUtil$DataCallback

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' //for Inmobi
    compile name: 'adcolony-sdk-3.2.1', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mmedia-6.4.0', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_alphab', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_appwall', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_appwallext', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_common', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_interstitial', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_mvdownloads', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_mvjscommon', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_mvnative', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_nativeex', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_offerwall', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_playercommon', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_reward', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_videocommon', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista_videofeeds', ext: 'aar'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'


    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: just replace `compile` with `implementation`

Comment: @ASN I did but getting another error,
"Program type already present: Android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$1

Comment: Can you check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49855016/6169668) and try to correct your accordingly and see

Comment: @ASN ,after some changes its giving diffrent error,

Comment: Error:Program type already present: android.support.v7.util.MessageThreadUtil$1$1

Comment: @intellij-amiya, this question is not duplicate. The problem is because of duplicated dependencies not about `compile` or `implementation`.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך indeed.

Comment: Now I am getting another error, "Program type already present : Android.support.v7.util.MessageThreadUtil$1$1

Comment: Please someone help..

Comment: I solved this exact issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54730492/3979290