# Build fails with 'Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function'

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

After updating my Firebase and Play Services dependencies as well as the Play Services Plugin my project fails to build. I've tried multiple Clean-Rebuilds and my app has MultiDex enabled. Reverting to my original dependency versions is also not an option as I added a dependency for cloud functions for which the latest version is incompatible with my other firebase dependencies. I can see the following under Android Issues

```
Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:  android.arch.core.util.Function, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I also see an error message under Run Tasks

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
```

My gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //Android Support
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1' //Maintain compatibility with com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1' //Maintain compatibility with com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1' //Maintain compatibility with com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'

    //Google Play
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

    //Stream Support
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:android-retrostreams:1.6.1'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:android-retroflow:1.6.1'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:android-retrofuture:1.6.1'

    //Location
    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'

    //Firebase UI
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.0.0'

    //Facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.31.0'

    //Search
    implementation 'com.algolia:algoliasearch-android:3.14.1'

    //Butterknife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    //UI Elements for layout staggering
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'

    //Image Handling Library
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.0'

    // UI Element for Country-code
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.2'

    // UI Element for OTP
    implementation 'com.github.GoodieBag:Pinview:v1.3'

    //Loading indicator using shimmer
    implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.0.0'

    //UI Element for Tooltip
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.15'

    //Date/Time Pickers for Hangout Creation
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.1'

    //UI Element from Drop-down boxes
    implementation('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v4'
    }

    //JSON Handling
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    //Permissions using RxPermissions
    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.5@aar'

    //RxBindings for Platform
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-recyclerview-v7:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-design:2.1.1'

    //Logging
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.6.0'

    //Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: version of google-services?

Comment: My project works with the latest version of `firebase core, database, messaging and auth` dependencies and latest `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'` the problem evolves when adding `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'` it shows this error `Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
`

Comment: For me, downgrading the dependency causing the problem solved the issue `'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'`

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

Comment: Downgrading  Firebase-UI to version 3.3.1 based on @OmarAbdelhafiz's comment and using firebase-firestore:15.0.0 seems to at least get the build to succeed. But this really isn't sustainable as at some point I'd like to be able to use updated dependencies.

Comment: accept the answer @KaranModi

Comment: Have you try to use the same version of firebase and google play services?

Comment: I have same problem and i endup with it by adding single line [Check out this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50095921/program-type-already-present-android-arch-lifecycle-livedata1/51697948#51697948)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I found the solution which some great guy posted on GitHub. Instead of downgrading your firebaseUI database, you can add arch common and runtime dependencies which are these:

```
//Arch
    implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.core:common:1.1.1"
```

Just add these in your app: module dependencies section and you know build it.

Comment: which firebaseUI version you are using in your dependencies

Comment: found it in one of google's firebase examples. However, you only need the runtime without  the common.

Comment: yeah true. but i added common just to be on the safe side.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me and makes more sense than downgrading a library

Comment: well i'm glad i could help you mate.

Comment: Is this considered patchwork? I am curious if it would be safe publishing my app with these dependencies. It works when I add them, just not certain of the reasoning and if this type of solution is considered practical / reliable.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, since it complies with the Android Documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes

Answer (score 15):

My project works with the latest version of `firebase core, database, messaging and auth` dependencies and latest `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

`App/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {

    // Tab Layout and ViewPager
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    // firebase dependencies
    // implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0' Source of error
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}
```

The problem evolves when adding `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'`

It shows this error:

> Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function
>
> Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

The solution was to downgrade `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'` to `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'` as follows:

`App/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {

    // Tab Layout and ViewPager
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    // firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.1' // No trouble in compiling
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
}
```

I hope Google will solve this issue in future updates.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Additionally, the compatible firestore dependency is 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing gradle files with:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

And Module:app grandle with:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug{
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }



}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //Android Support
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1' //Maintain compatibility with com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1' //Maintain compatibility with com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1' //Maintain compatibility with com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'

    //Google Play
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

    //Stream Support
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport:1.6.0'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport-cfuture:1.6.0'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport-atomic:1.6.0'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport-flow:1.6.0'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport-literal:1.6.0'

    //Location
    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'

    //Firebase UI
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.0.0'

    //Facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.32.0'

    //Search
    implementation 'com.algolia:algoliasearch-android:3.14.1'

    //Butterknife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    //UI Elements for layout staggering
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'

    //Image Handling Library
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.0'

    // UI Element for Country-code
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.2'

    // UI Element for OTP
    implementation 'com.github.GoodieBag:Pinview:v1.3'

    //Loading indicator using shimmer
    implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.0.0'

    //UI Element for Tooltip
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.15'

    //Date/Time Pickers for Hangout Creation
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.1'

    //UI Element from Drop-down boxes
    implementation('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v4'
    }

    //JSON Handling
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    //Permissions using RxPermissions
    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.5@aar'

    //RxBindings for Platform
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-recyclerview-v7:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-design:2.1.1'

    //Logging
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.6.0'

    //Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Not working for me. Maybe in my case is some conflict between subdependencies
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzxk

Comment: Yes maybe, try to add new google play service: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

Comment: @KaraModi could you please edit qestion and add whole project and module:App grandle so i can help you

Comment: @KaraModi i hope this new answer will help you

Comment: "minSdkVersion 24 <-- Because for lower sdk android-retrostreams-1.6.1.jar display error". You must be doing something wrong then. *android-retrostreams* definitely *doesn't* have that `minSdkVersion 24` requirement.

Comment: Your theory is wrong. Both [android-retrostreams](https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrostreams) and [streamsupport](https://github.com/stefan-zobel/streamsupport) work nicely with a `minSdkVersion` of *14* or *15*.

Comment: @Sartorius So copy grandle files and try to make project with sdk version below 24, you will get error because one of these libraries use Java > 7. For Java 8, most language features are available on all platforms, but one or two require a minimum SDK version of 24. Check the answer in link.

Comment: I work with these libraries on a daily basis. I don't know what the issue is but it's almost certainly not with these libraries.

Comment: FWIW, I've checked your linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230781/relationship-between-os-version-api-level-and-java-version/47231030#47231030) and it doesn't say anything that is applicable to the above mentioned libraries.

Comment: yeah i fix my asnwer the first grandle file miss some libraries from net.sourceforge.streamsupport so now it works perfect with sdk version 16, i change my answer @KaraModi you could check the code

Comment: @Sartorius yea i think some libraries use Java 9 but is my fault

Comment: Yup, maybe. Whichever that is, it's certainly neither *android-retrostreams* nor *streamsupport*

Comment: I'm reasonably certain this is a firebase or google services dependency specific issue as nothing else was changed prior to the build failing.

Comment: Is this something Firebase could correct in a future release? I have a workaround but it is driving me nuts and wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

I had the same problem above, and it was because i didn't include the core.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

**Noted some of your dependency is 16.0.1, would suggest you upgrade the core to 16.0.1 instead of 16.0.0.**

Have enclosed my dependency below for reference, hope you find it useful.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
```

Comment: At the time this issue was posted, com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0 was the latest build available.

Comment: Anyway if it really doesn't work, try using the older version:
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.1'

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the below implemention on your build.gradle in android studio. Hope it helps.

```
 implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:$version"
 implementation "android.arch.core:common:$version"
```