# In current theme failed to find style 'floatingActionButtonStyle'

Tags: android, android-appcompat, floating-action-button

Failed to find style '`floatingActionButtonStyle`' in current theme.

**I even tried doing this in my style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton</item>
</style>
```

It did not work. I used Base.theme because of appcompat problem I was facing . **My appcompat is** - `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1`

Here is the XML file where error is shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"

tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    />
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Message..."
        android:inputType="text" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_of_message"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fab"
    android:dividerHeight="16dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Build.gradle(app)

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hp.chatapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //add library
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
   // implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'

    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please add this gradle inside your gradle file "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"

Comment: how to add? by implementaion ? @FalduJaldeep

Comment: @katty12 I see that it is already added. You might have to change both appcompat and design versions to `27.1.1`. As I know both of the libraries have to have the same version and `alpha` and `beta` might not be stable.

Comment: @grrigore I changed both to 27.1.1  but this is showing - This support library should not use a different version(27) than the compileSdkVersion(28). It will cause any problem in future?

Comment: @katty12 I think yes. Then try to get both `appcompat` and `design` to the same version. I see it's `alpha1` and `beta01`. `28.0.0-alpha1` might be right for both of them. (if the line with appcompat or design is coloured in yellow you might try to place the cursor above it and it will suggest you to change the version if required)

Comment: @grrigore It couldnt compile , it shows- Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function

Comment: @grrigore 28.0.0-alpha1 doesnt support FloatingActionButton style.

Comment: @katty12 That might be caused by `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'`. Try to comment this line and see if the floatingActionButton works.

Comment: Can you post the hole build.gradle file? Also do you want to use compileSdkVersion 28? I'd rather use 27 as some of the libraries in 28 are still in beta/alpha

Comment: @grrigore commenting it worked. I am half in my way of doing an app that needs firebase so I will require its implementation in future. It will still give me the problem? currently I used 27.1.1 because 28.0.0-apha1 has a bug , it doesn't support floatingActionButton style. I hope there wont be any problem in future

Comment: @grrigore I am changing it to 27

Comment: @katty12 Regarding the `firebase-ui-database` you might have to downgrade the version to `3.1.1`. Check you this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524672/build-fails-with-program-type-already-present-android-arch-core-util-function

Comment: just added full gradle.build

Comment: @katty12 change `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the comments this is what I came up to:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hp.chatapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //add library
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    // implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
    // consider using implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.1'
    // see the question below

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I suggest using `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` 27 because, as you noticed,

> 28.0.0-alpha1 doesnt support FloatingActionButton style.

and might also cause problems as it is in `alpha version`.

Question about `firebase-ui-database` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524672/build-fails-with-program-type-already-present-android-arch-core-util-function).

**Extra:** You can search for libraries [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7?repo=google) and see how many people are using it or the release date.