# implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0 error

Tags: android, build.gradle

when add this in Gradle 
`implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0`
this error appears:

```
Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show me your Manifest.xml please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build fails with 'Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524672/build-fails-with-program-type-already-present-android-arch-core-util-function)