# Firebase Auth AndroidX Dependency not found while building release and debug apk

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, flutter, firebase-authentication

See [flutter issue 27982](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27982). How can I resolve this? (Note: shortened url in `firebase_auth` error message has been replaced with full link).

See Edit at bottom.

Edit 2: Here is a pre-AndroidX [`pubspec.yaml`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27901#issuecomment-464586215) with some common dependencies.

---

To my understanding, the dependency requested by `firebase_auth` (`androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:26.0.0`) doesn't exist; I can only find `v1.0.0` on [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.legacy/legacy-support-v4?repo=google).

Edit: Also throws a similar error on `flutter build apk --debug`

### Steps to Reproduce

```
1. Migrate to AndroidX

2. Include `firebase_auth` in `pubspec.yaml`

3. run `flutter build apk`
```

### Logs

```
$ flutter build apk
Initializing gradle...                                       0.5s
Resolving dependencies...                                   13.6s
Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of firebase_auth will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:26.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:26.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :firebase_auth > com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                        6.9s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

### Pubspec

```
name: timeswap_core
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
# 
# the number after '+' is the version code -- version name is before
version: 0.1.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cloud_firestore:

  firebase_auth:

  google_sign_in:

  dotenv:

  colorize:

  progress_hud:

  square_in_app_payments:

  uuid:

  flutter_slidable:

  flutter_sms:

  dynamic_theme:

  shared_preferences:

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  test: 1.5.1
  flutter_launcher_icons:

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - cfg/env.json
    - assets/   

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

### Android build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.2, 0.99.99]'
        //classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1'
    }

    subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
          && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
           details.useVersion "27.1.1"
        }

        // if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.legacy'  && details.requested.name.contains('legacy-support-v4')) {
        //     details.useVersion "1.0.0"
        // }
     }
  }
}
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### App build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.timeswap.timeswapcore"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'

    // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524672/build-fails-with-program-type-already-present-android-arch-core-util-function
    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

### Flutter Doctor

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.1.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.556], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.1.8 at C:\flutter_windows_v0.11.11-beta\flutter
    • Framework revision 985ccb6d14 (5 weeks ago), 2019-01-08 13:45:55 -0800
    • Engine revision 7112b72cc2
    • Dart version 2.1.1 (build 2.1.1-dev.0.1 ec86471ccc)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Jackie\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 32.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    • Dart plugin version 182.5124
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.io/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[√] VS Code (version 1.31.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Jackie\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.22.3

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.26.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.22.3

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM N910T • c253d892 • android-arm • Android 6.0.1 (API 23)
```

EDIT:

Added `classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0'` to android `build.gradle` and got a different error message.

Adding `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'` to app `build.gradle` did NOT help.

```
C:\flutter_windows_v0.11.11-beta\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-0.0.4+2\android\src\main\java\com\appleeducate\fluttersms\FlutterSmsPlugin.java:12: error: cannot find symbolimport androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.content.Intent;
                                               ^
  symbol:   class content
  location: class AppCompatActivity
C:\flutter_windows_v0.11.11-beta\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-0.0.4+2\android\src\main\java\com\appleeducate\fluttersms\FlutterSmsPlugin.java:27: error: incompatible types: Activity cannot be converted to AppCompatActivity
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(new FlutterSmsPlugin(registrar.activity()));
                                                                        ^
C:\flutter_windows_v0.11.11-beta\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-0.0.4+2\android\src\main\java\com\appleeducate\fluttersms\FlutterSmsPlugin.java:57: error: cannot find symbol    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class FlutterSmsPlugin
C:\flutter_windows_v0.11.11-beta\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-0.0.4+2\android\src\main\java\com\appleeducate\fluttersms\FlutterSmsPlugin.java:57: error: cannot find symbol    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class FlutterSmsPlugin
C:\flutter_windows_v0.11.11-beta\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-0.0.4+2\android\src\main\java\com\appleeducate\fluttersms\FlutterSmsPlugin.java:57: error: cannot find symbol    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable Intent
  location: class FlutterSmsPlugin
C:\flutter_windows_v0.11.11-beta\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-0.0.4+2\android\src\main\java\com\appleeducate\fluttersms\FlutterSmsPlugin.java:90: error: cannot find symbol    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
    ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class FlutterSmsPlugin
C:\flutter_windows_v0.11.11-beta\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-0.0.4+2\android\src\main\java\com\appleeducate\fluttersms\FlutterSmsPlugin.java:90: error: cannot find symbol    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                        ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class FlutterSmsPlugin
C:\flutter_windows_v0.11.11-beta\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-0.0.4+2\android\src\main\java\com\appleeducate\fluttersms\FlutterSmsPlugin.java:92: error: cannot find symbol    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                       ^
  symbol:   variable Intent
  location: class FlutterSmsPlugin
C:\flutter_windows_v0.11.11-beta\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-0.0.4+2\android\src\main\java\com\appleeducate\fluttersms\FlutterSmsPlugin.java:93: error: cannot find symbol    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    ^
  symbol:   variable Intent
  location: class FlutterSmsPlugin
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
9 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_sms:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of firebase_auth will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See [url in error messages above] for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       10.2s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the issue that was [originally filed for Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27982) have been closed and moved to [FlutterFire](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/441) as this is generally an issue with Firebase plugins.

Based on the update from the [related issue filed in GitHub](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/17), the fixes [have been released](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/17#issuecomment-680145777) on the newer version of FlutterFire plugins.

> Hey
>
> Our rework of the the FlutterFire plugins to depend on a shared 'core'
> (which controls the versions of the Firebase SDKs used on Android) as
> part of the FlutterFire roadmap was published over a week ago with a
> ton of fixes and new features.
>
> Please could you try the new versions and see if this is still an
> issue? Additionally the documentation site now covers Android
> installation, https://firebase.flutter.dev
>
> If this is still an issue then please submit a new up to date GitHub
> issue.
>
> For help migrating to the new plugins please see the new migration
> guide: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration