# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

i've ben facing this and tried to solve without any luck. Below are the error out put and my gradle file. **Before marking this as duplicate** i would like to point out almost all the suggested ways didn't work for me.

[image: error output]

[image: my gradle file]

**What i have tried so far**

1. set multiDexEnabled to true
2. un-commented the line org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in my gradle.properties file
3. change my application class to extend MultiDexApplication instead of Application
4. Check if i have duplicates class and i don't
5. updated android studio and google play services to latest versions (3.1.2 for android studio)
6. cleaned the project and even deleted .gradle file

any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if anyone in the future will be having having this, the correct way for me was to check my library versions that utilize live data. As the error suggests, it had an association with live data. You don't have to implement live data to get this error but utilizing any library that has connection with live data can lead to this problem.
In my case it was **Firebase ui library** as i updated android support library to 27.1.0.
so i also updated firebase ui ,library to 3.2.2.
as per google, this was an ***Intended behavior*** so the only thing to fix that is to update firebase ui library to a version that supports library 27.1.0.

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166145/6660930)